# How to fire an event on clicking the checkbox in handsontable?

Tags: typescript, handsontable, aurelia

I have created a handsontable and the data is being loaded from the server.
I have a checkbox and I want to run a function whenever the checkbox is toggled. My code is written in typescript/aurelia. I was reading the handsontable docs and I think the afterChange event might be able to do this but I am not sure. I even wrote a custom renderer where I create my own checkbox and added an event listener to it but I get a script error from aurelia.js and the table. Here is the code:

```
this.options.colHeaders = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'];
this.options.columns = [
 {data:"value1", renderer: myCustomRenderer1},
 {data:"value2"},
 {data: "value3", type:"checkbox", renderer: myCheckboxRenderer} 
 ];
this.apiData.forEach((d) => {
 d["value1"]={
 "col1":d.col1, "handler": () => {
      return this.openModal(d.id);
             }
 };
 d["value3"]={
 "flag": d.flag, "handler": () => {
      return this.functionIwantToRunAfterCheckboxValueHasChanged(d.id);
             }
 };
});
```

Comment: Setting up the scenario in the [aurelia-plunker](http://bit.ly/aurelia-plunker) will guarantee someone can reproduce your issue and help you